# Password Encription (SHA1) by Oracle Weblogic 10.3.2

Tags: encryption, weblogic, sha1, weblogic-10.x, salt

Weblogic 10.3.2 uses SHA-1 (and others) for pass encryption. For example the following password:

> abcdefg

with SHA-1 encryption results:

> teshjSf9GOUIvRHljjMafld8YsWTlQ4=

I have tried various websites that do SHA-! encryption, but none that result with the above answer. There is a possibility Salt is being utilized. Basically, what steps were taken to get the result.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passwords should be salted. Hopefully even Oracle knows that. If so, you'll need the salt for a particular password.

You'll also need to know the number of times the hash function was applied, and how the salt was combined with the password. I doubt this is considered a published interface, so WebLogic is unlikely to document this.

Comment: Thanks @erickson. You are right about the salt being used. Looks like contacting WegLogic would help.

Comment: "DOMAIN_HOME/security/SerializedSystemIni.dat" is the salt file

Answer (score 1):

try this, it works for weblogic SQL Authenticator

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
String password="abcdef"; 
System.out.println("{SHA-1}" 
                 + new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder()
                .encode(java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1")
                .digest(password.getBytes())));
}
```